Angular 16 with datetime picker
Is there a recommended approach to implement a datetime picker with Angular 16 and bootstrap?  I would like to implement a form where the user clicks a button which opens a datetime picker.  I have read up on ng-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap and angular-material, but there doesn't seem to be a recommended approach that does both date and time in the one dialog.
Any suggestions?

Hi,
ng-bootstrap doesn't provide a combined datetime picker, you can achieve the desired functionality by integrating its datepicker and timepicker components into a custom component of your own (not sure how it would look.
Have you tried looking into this: https://primeng.org/calendar . PrimeNg is a great library but it all depends on your project.
